# why array not sort properly in function

Tags: java, function, sorting

[image]

```
public int[] sortedSquares(int[] nums) {
    int size = nums.length;
    int result[] = new int[size];
    
    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++)
    {
        int min =i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
        
            if(nums[j]<nums[min])
            
                min = j;        
                int temp = nums[min];
                nums[min] = nums[i];
                nums[i]=temp;
        
    
    }
      for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
      {
          result[i] = nums[i]*nums[i];
      }
    
    return result;
    
}
```

this is from leetcode question "Squares of a Sorted Array" I sorted it and the result come out not sort. i dont know what happen? if i use Arrays.sort(result) it will work, but why this code not working?

[image]

Comment: i try it not work,,

Comment: yes,  but it work for the void function

Comment: so i made void sort(int arr[]) function it is correct,  but it does not work with return int sortSquare[];

Comment: i post the picture

Comment: so like we need use math.abs?

Comment: NO¹, you need to sort AFTER squaring (@expeeriment code is correct, indentation is wrong - only `min = j` must be inside `if` and `for`, swaping should be done after the loop - the code with black background is correctly indented)  **¹** you can use `abs` before sorting, but that will make code even harder to understand, and no need, just sort after squaring (squares should sorted, so sort the squares {if input should be squared then sort the input})

Comment: actually code on right pane (black background) is also badly indented, just less bad than the one on the left - please get used to ALWAYS use `{}` for `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, ... and let the IDE indent your code (if you don't want to do it)

Comment: the right one is just sorting, and i change the code like you said not working, maybe i did something wrong

Comment: you are right, need to be squaring first, but the sorting is not working, they never got swap, but it got swap on right side, maybe it has to do with address? or something, if i just do Arrays.sort(result), it will pass the test,  but how come this sort is not working,

Answer (score 1):

i didnt catch what @user16320675 mentioned about the squaring after sorting at first glance, but yeah he is right. This should give the output you want.

```
 public int[] sortedSquares(int[] nums) {
    int size = nums.length;
    int result[] = new int[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        result[i] = nums[i]*nums[i]; //square items
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) { //sort squared items
            if (result[j] < result[min]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        int temp = result[min];
        result[min] = result[i];
        result[i] = temp;

    }

    return result;

}
```

[image]

Comment: it... passes the test case you were asking for...